# mantener búsqueda en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta funcion para buscar en el contenido de una pagina, el caso es que solo funciona si escribo en ella, pero si ya hay texto escrito no filtra nada. 
¿que podría hacer para que si hay texto ya escrito también filtre?

```
var buscador_ = [];
function Buscador(div) {
    $("#buscador_"+div).keyup(function(){
        var buscador_Inarticulos = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        $(".buskibuski_"+div).each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(buscador_Inarticulos, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
            } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
            }
        });
    });
$('#buscador_'+div).keypress(function(e){ if(e.which == 13){ return false; } }); //evitar el enter en el buscador
};
```

Aquí en el sniped he conseguido replicar mas o menos el codigo, lo único que no he conseguido replicar es que al volver del botón ocultar yo recargo los resultados del listado de colores de nuevo. Con lo que los que había desaparecen previo a darle a ocultar y aparecen unos nuevos.

```js
 Buscador('InColores'); //llamo buscador
 //buscador chachi
var buscador_ = [];
function Buscador(div) {
 $("#buscador_"+div).keyup(function(){
  var buscador = $(this).val(), count = 0;
  $(".buskibuski_"+div).each(function(){
   if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(buscador, "i")) < 0) {
   $(this).fadeOut();
   } else {
   $(this).show();
   count++;
   }
  });
 });
$('#buscador_'+div).keypress(function(e){ if(e.which == 13){ return false; } }); //evitar el enter en el buscador
};

function VerMas(id) {
 $(".resultados_"+id).hide("fold", 500);
  $(".formulario_"+id).delay(500).hide("fade", "300");
 $(".formulario_grande_"+id).delay(890).slideToggle("400");
};

function VerMenos(id) {
 $(".formulario_grande_"+id).delay(890).slideToggle("400");
 $(".resultados_"+id).show("fold", 500);
  $(".formulario_"+id).delay(500).show("fade", "300");
   $.post("http://google.es", {suggest: txt}, function(result){
   $(".resultados_"+id).html(result); })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="formulario_InColores">
<ul class="caja">
 <li class="buscador">
  <ul>
   <li><label>Nombre:</label><input type="text" id="buscador_InColores" name="BusNombre" placeholder="Buscador" value=""></li>
      <li><button onClick="VerMas('InColores')">Ocultar</button>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
 
<div id="doc_InPresupuesto" class="formulario_grande_InColores" style="display: none;">hola
<button onClick="VerMenos('InColores')">Mostrar</button>
</div>

<div class="resultados_InColores">
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="primera">Nombre</th>
    <th class="ultima 10porcien">Modificar</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;AZUL 397</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('AZUL 397'); $('#IdColor').val('182');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Aguamar</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Aguamar'); $('#IdColor').val('117');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Albero</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Albero'); $('#IdColor').val('136');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Amarillo</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Amarillo'); $('#IdColor').val('131');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Amarillo Borrar</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Amarillo Borrar'); $('#IdColor').val('162');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('140');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('173');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('174');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('175');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Marino</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Marino'); $('#IdColor').val('139');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Marino</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Marino'); $('#IdColor').val('172');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Marino</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Marino'); $('#IdColor').val('176');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Antracita 852</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Antracita 852'); $('#IdColor').val('177');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Arena 269</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Arena 269'); $('#IdColor').val('195');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Asfalto</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Asfalto'); $('#IdColor').val('251');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Azabache</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Azabache'); $('#IdColor').val('134');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Azul</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Azul'); $('#IdColor').val('69');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
  <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Azul Jeans 164</td>
  <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Azul Jeans 164'); $('#IdColor').val('197');" value="Modificar"></td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "pero si ya hay texto escrito" , no entiendo muy bien

Comment: la capa del buscador y resultados se oculta o aparece (sin cerrar la pagina) según pulses un botón y cuando reaparece sale el texto escrito pero no filtrados los resultados @CamiloVasquez

Comment: Y cual es la función que se ejecuta cuando se le da click al botón para que haga aparecer el buscador, tienes forma de hacer un ejemplo funcional para ejecutar en el snippet ?

Comment: Voy a intentarlo a ver si consigo hacer un funcional.

Comment: No es entendible, a que te refieres con el "contenido" ? el html ? una base de datos ? , un array ? un objeto ?  y el ejemplo funcional ?¿ , que recibe esa regex ? , deberías rehacer tu pregunta con un ejemplo funcional

Comment: Ya he puesto mas o menos un ejemplo funcional. Como explico arriba no se como replicar la vuelta al listado... pero seria cargar con $.post la pagina con el array de colores que había previamente

Comment: Acabo de probar y funciona, pero volví a leer tu pregunta y me encontré con esto "lo único que no he conseguido replicar es que al volver del botón ocultar yo recargo los resultados del listado de colores de nuevo" entonces pregunto, para que vuelves a recargar todos los resultados ??

Comment: Por si se han agregado nuevos o para agregar al listado el que acabo de insertar... el ocultar es un formulario para insertar uno nuevo. @CamiloVasquez en Efecto si no hago esa recarga se mantiene la búsqueda,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es volver a llamar lo mismo que realizas en el evento `keyup` de tu input.

```js
Buscador('InColores');

var buscador_ = [];
function Buscador(div) {
    $("#buscador_"+div).keyup(function(){
        procesar();
    });
    
    $('#buscador_'+div).keypress(function(e){ if(e.which == 13){ return false; } }); //evitar el enter en el buscador
};

function VerMas(id) {
    $(".resultados_"+id).hide("fold", 500);
    $(".formulario_"+id).delay(500).hide("fade", "300");
    $(".formulario_grande_"+id).delay(890).slideToggle("400");
};

function VerMenos(id) {
    $(".buskibuski_InColores").each(function(){
        $(this).show();
    }); // Esto lo agregué para simular la recarga de los datos
    
    if($("#buscador_InColores").val() != ''){
        procesar();
    }

    $(".formulario_grande_"+id).delay(890).slideToggle("400");
    $(".resultados_"+id).show("fold", 500);
    $(".formulario_"+id).delay(500).show("fade", "300");

    /*$.post("http://google.es", {suggest: txt}, function(result){
        $(".resultados_"+id).html(result);
    })*/ //Esto lo comenté para que no me sacara errores en mi consola
};

function procesar(){
    var buscador = $("#buscador_InColores").val(), count = 0;
    $(".buskibuski_InColores").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(buscador, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="formulario_InColores">
<ul class="caja">
    <li class="buscador">
        <ul>
            <li><label>Nombre:</label><input type="text" id="buscador_InColores" name="BusNombre" placeholder="Buscador" value=""></li>
      <li><button onClick="VerMas('InColores')">Ocultar</button>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
    
<div id="doc_InPresupuesto" class="formulario_grande_InColores" style="display: none;">hola
<button onClick="VerMenos('InColores')">Mostrar</button>
</div>

<div class="resultados_InColores">
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="primera">Nombre</th>
                <th class="ultima 10porcien">Modificar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;AZUL 397</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('AZUL 397'); $('#IdColor').val('182');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Aguamar</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Aguamar'); $('#IdColor').val('117');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Albero</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Albero'); $('#IdColor').val('136');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Amarillo</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Amarillo'); $('#IdColor').val('131');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Amarillo Borrar</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Amarillo Borrar'); $('#IdColor').val('162');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('140');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('173');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('174');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Blanco</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Blanco'); $('#IdColor').val('175');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Marino</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Marino'); $('#IdColor').val('139');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Marino</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Marino'); $('#IdColor').val('172');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Anclas Marino</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Anclas Marino'); $('#IdColor').val('176');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Antracita 852</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Antracita 852'); $('#IdColor').val('177');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Arena 269</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Arena 269'); $('#IdColor').val('195');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Asfalto</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Asfalto'); $('#IdColor').val('251');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Azabache</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Azabache'); $('#IdColor').val('134');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Azul</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Azul'); $('#IdColor').val('69');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr class="buskibuski buskibuski_InColores">
        <td class="izquierda_listados veinte">&nbsp;Azul Jeans 164</td>
        <td class="centro_listados diez"><input type="button" class="boton" onclick="SoloMas('Colores'); $('#AVCColor').val('Azul Jeans 164'); $('#IdColor').val('197');" value="Modificar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Ten en cuenta los dos comentarios que hice dentro del código, si tienes dudas con gusto las resolveré.